# Text Tab - Letter Spacing

Tags: docusignapi

I am using Docusign via the PHP SDK on a project I am currently working on. I am using existing PDF forms that I need to insert text into dynamically and I am using the Text Tab to do this. Everything is working fine but on one of the forms I need to have field's letters positioned within pre-defined boxes, which requires me to have letter spacing so that each letter is aligned within a box. Is there any way to change the spacing between letters in a Text Tab so that I can get the alignment right?

Answer (score 1):

The Docusign REST API documentation for [Text Tab](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Text%20Tab.htm) suggests that you can specify font/fontSize/bold/italic properties to adjust the font. There is no option for letter spacing.